# Which Field to choose for storing Raw HTML inside a Peewee Model

Tags: python, peewee

I'm using Peewee ORM with SQLite DB and i want to store chuck of HTML inside DB

I'm stucked between choosing a best suited field for storing HTML basically whole webpage including css js html etc whatever that webpage contains the webpage is being loaded via `r = requests.get(url)`

My Code:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Page(BaseModel):
    raw_html = CharField(unique=True) # stucked here between choosing a best suited field
```

It's basically for scraping pages from site save the whole page or pages inside DB and since it'll be in DB i can later deal with that data extracting info or i can do whatever i want to do with it

i know i can use other scraper libs like scrap.py etc but i want to do it this way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CharField` is not a good choice since it would require you to know the length of the data beforehand. Use [`TextField`](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/fields.html#TextField) instead - it was made *to store arbitrarily large strings*:

```
class Page(BaseModel):
    raw_html = TextField(unique=True)
```

Comment: Don't add a unique constraint, that'll slow things down. If you need to ensure uniqueness, hash the content using something like md5 then put an index on the hash. Much more efficient.